# Android. How to programatically change background color of button

Tags: android, dynamic-programming, android-drawable, android-button, android-styles

I need to create Button programatically. And my button can be randomly colored. However, I need to set the background color of the button and also the background color when the button is in a state PRESSED.

That is, the background color of the button in its normal state should be different from the background color when the user pressed the button.

For example, when I need a different background for a button, depending on the state, I use a selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_not_pressed" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_not_pressed" />
</selector>
```

And in my xml for button:

```
  android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
```

This is a working solution if you know the background you need in advance. However, in my case, I am dynamically getting the background for the button (pressed_bg and not_pressed_bg) and therefore this method does not work for me. Is it possible to implement this programmatically?

P.S. I need pressed effect

Please, help me.

Comment: You would like to create a button which is when you press that button bg color should be change and button bg itself should change automatically / randomly and restriction is bg color and background color shouldn't be same am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I need a button for which I get the background color in the normal state and the background color in the pressed state.

Answer (score 1):

> You can create a color code list and pass the color code randomly on a button click to set button background color.

```
yourButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0060AB"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can programaticaly check and set the colors like this.

```
if(someButton.isPressed){
     val pressedRandomColor = getPressedRandomColor()
     someButton.setBackgroundColor(pressedRandomColor)
 }else {
     val randomColor = getRandomColor()
     someButton.setBackgroundColor(randomColor)
 }
```

The logic for getPressedRandomColor() and getRandomColor() you need to define by yourself, it should return Int value.